# AWS Elastic Beanstalk eb deploy GIT

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How can I pull two repositories from git during eb deploy so when it is deployed, it has the following structure:
/var/app/current/REPO_1
/var/app/current/REPO_2

It must be somehow via .ebextension config, but I couldn't figure it out. Please help!